# Set value from SpinBox to variable

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qspinbox

I need to set the `spinBox` value to my variable, which is outside the function. 
So here I have variable time and wanna set it to `spinBox` value:

```
void MainWindow::on_spinBox_valueChanged(int arg1)
{
    arg1 = ui->spinBox->value();
}
```

I wanna store `arg1` to time variable.

Shall I define time as global variable?

Comment: Use a reference. `int & arg1`

Comment: No, this slot definition is correct without the reference. You're misunderstanding the direction; see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When the spin box value changes, the `on_spinBox_valueChanged` is called with the new value of the spin box. You're trying to set that input parameter to the spin box value, which does nothing and is, in fact, already the value passed in. You need to create a member variable to store the result. A global also works, although that's certainly not a good practice.

Comment: Can u give me an example, how do this? Cause I know only way with global

Comment: @Tosik In `MainWindow`, add a member variable `_spinBoxChangeTime` (or something like that) and set that equal to `ui->spinBox->value()`. That's what @goug is referring to.